# Resource Feasibility Definition

Tags: microeconomics

[image: Definition]

What is this saying intuitively? I can't seem to wrap my head around the interpretation of this definition. I do see how if we incorporate price, I can get to the problems solved individually by the household and firm but not quite getting this concept of resource feasibility.
Note: 
$X_i$ and $Y_j$ are the consumptions and production bundles respectively, and $w_i$ is the endowment bundle, $i$ is for an household, and $j$ represents a firm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty self explanatory, you cannot consume more than you produced or you been given as an endowment.

Hence the allocation is resource feasible if:

$$\sum x = \sum y + \sum \omega $$

For example, this would not be feasible:

$$\sum x > \sum y + \sum \omega $$

Consumption cannot outstrip production plus the initial endowment.

Next this condition on resource allocation would also be feasible

$$\sum x \leq \sum y + \sum \omega $$

But usually the less or equal is replaced by equality, as optimizing agents would use up all their resources, not wasting anything.

Comment: $\leq$ also assumes free disposal.

Comment: @Giskard yes that’s typically left unstated but thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2):

An allocation is *feasible* if the aggregate consumption can be covered by production and the endowments.